# How to design a tabbar inside a view

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I need to make this view:

[image]

A view on top of the tab bar with some data. (image, name, text, ...)
tab bar has a 3 page and every page has a separate view

When user scroll up, tabbar will be scrolling top of the page and a `UILable` stands top of tab bar. It can be show with some fading animation (not important right now)

this is after scrolling:

[image]

I search in cocopods but I didn't find solution.

---- EDITE
I want to know how to put uitabbar inside a view. Is it possible ?
If yes, How to change just sub view of tab bar when I change tab bars!

Comment: Too broad. It's not our job to write the code to fulfill your spec. It's _your_ job.

Comment: @matt, I didn't want to you write me code! I just wants to know the way. I wants to know. Is it possible with Apple standards. BTW thanks for replay :/

Comment: "I wants to know. Is it possible with Apple standards" But that is not what you asked. In fact, you didn't ask _anything_. You just said "I need to make this view". That's not even a question. Think about what your question is, then ask it.

Comment: @matt, I edited my question. Is it clear now ? (I'm not ordering some solution. It's for my english. and sorry for my english. I just need help if there will be any help ;) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know how to put uitabbar inside a view. Is it possible ? If yes, How to change just sub view of tab bar when I change tab bars!

Yes, but I wouldn't describe the thing you are showing in your screen shot as a "tab bar". It is a UISegmentedControl. So all you have to do is respond to the user tapping on a segment of the UISegmentedControl by substituting one view for another, and that's easy to do.